# Replace strings in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to replace strings in an array. Right now I'm using a `forEach`-loop and a `switch`, which doesn't feel very elegant:

```
let result = [];
source.forEach(el => {
    switch (el) {
        case 'replace':
            result.push('with this'); break;
        case ...:
            ...;
        default:
            result.push(el);
    }
});
return result.join(',');
```

What I want to get is a replacement of the elements with another string or using the original string if there is no match.

The source array has 50 elements, the replacement array has 30 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases where you desire a one-in-one-out manipulation of an array, the `.map` function is preferred:

```
return source.map(el => el === 'replace' ? 'with this' : el).join(',');
```

**EDIT** I see you've updated the question and you actually have 30 different strings that you wish to replace.  In this case you should use a `Map` that is pre-populated with the "before" and "after" strings:

```
let replaceFunc = (function() {

    let replace = new Map([
        ['replace', 'with this']
    ]);

    return source => source.map(el => replace.has(el) ? replace.get(el) : el).join(',');
 })();
```

The IIFE is used to ensure one-time initialisation of the `Map`, and the returned function that is closed over the `Map` is assigned to `replaceFunc`.

```
> replaceFunc(['replace']);
"with this"
```

Comment: The `new Map()` part doesn't work for me. But I don't see why. I don't get an error, but I don't get any output either. Doesn't `replace.get(el)` need an index?

Comment: It works for me on Chrome 54 (I assumed you're using a modern browser or interpreter given you used ES6 arrow syntax in the question).   The parameter to `replace.get()` is just the key, so in this case a word from the source array.

Answer (score 1):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is an alternative

```
var result = source.map(function (e) {
    return e === 'replace' ? 'with this' : e;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var sample = ["aaa", "bbb", "replaceMe", "ccc", "ddd"];
var result = sample.map(function(ele, inx) {
   if (ele == "replaceMe") {
      return "newText";
   } else {
      return ele;
   }
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below making the sample example for replace :-

```
  String originalString = "hello";
  String newString = originalString.replace('E', 'x');
  System.out.println( newString );
```

instantly refer - http://javadevnotes.com/java-string-replace-tutorial-and-examples

Comment: This question is about _JavaScript_, not _Java_ !